# Shell Script & Stored Procedure - Literal Format Error

Tags: oracle, shell, stored-procedures

I have a shell script that calls an Oracle Stored Procedure.  The SP has two parameters - the first is of type VARCHAR2 and the second is of type DATE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_SCHEMA.MY_SP_NAME(firstParameter IN VARCHAR2, dateParameter IN DATE)
IS

BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Successfully called Procedure');

END;
/
```

In my shell script, I'm trying to execute the procedure using the following command:

```
echo "EXECUTE MY_SCHEMA.MY_SP_NAME('TEST', '20170909') " | $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus $ORAUSER/$ORAPASS
```

The problem is that when the script runs I get the following error:  ORA-01861: literal does not match format string.  My guess is that there is an issue with the '20170809' value that I'm passing to the date parameter but I'm unsure how to resolve this.  Any help is appreciated.

(PS: The ORACLE_HOME/USER/PASS environment variables are all set correctly and I can successfully run SQLPLUS from the script so there are no problems connecting to the Oracle database)

Comment: Please try `... ('TEST', date '2017-09-09')`. It is [universal syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) for dates, not depending on local settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the `to_date` function:

```
Execute my_schema.my_sp_name(‘test’,to_date(‘20170909’, ‘yyyymmdd’))
```

Or use ISO date format in your date parameter.